# How to set tab stops after whitespaces in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, formatting

I'm trying to set tab stops in LaTeX in the tabbing environment. My problem is that I want to set a tab stop after a number of whitespaces. The problem is that LaTeX of course ignores multiple whitespaces, and it seems to only support setting tab stops after actual text.

What I would like to be able to do is format the arrows below so that they line up together.

```
A   -> B
CD  -> A 
BDD -> F
```

The problem is that the extra spaces after the characters on the left of the arrows are ignored for the purposes of setting the tab stop. What is the solution?

Comment: Not clear. Do you want to replace the meaning of whitespaces by tab stop char? Do you want to replace the meaning of pair (three, ...) whitespaces by tab stop command? What is `->`? Is it `$\to$`? Why the extra space after `A` is the problem? Don't you want to ignore multiple whitespaces?

Comment: Well if you put a tab stop after `A`, then it sits directly after 'A' when what I want to do is put a tab stop that sits just after position that the rightmost character on the left hand side. I've expanded the example, does that make it clearer?

Comment: May be you should use `\halign`, `\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}` or something like that instead of `tabbing`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `tabbing` environment allows to set tab stops and position text accordingly; it may be used to simulate simple tables.

`\=` in the first line sets a tab stop, `\>` advances to the next tab stop in the second line and below.

Please note that `tabbing` does not expand tab stops, so you need to ensure they are placed wide enough from each other. For example, I put some nonbreakable spaces after `A` in the first line:

```
\begin{tabbing}
A~~~~ \= $\to$ \= B \\
CD \> $\to$ \> A \\
BDD \> $\to$ \> F \\
\end{tabbing}
```

The result looks like

[image: result screenshot]

Using tables (e.g. `tabular`) is often easier, but `tabbing` allows to redefine tab points later, so it may be used to simulate indented text, like source code.

See also: [LaTeX: tabbing](http://www.tac.dk/cgi-bin/info2www?%28latex%29tabbing).

Comment: This is exactly the sort of solution I had in mind. Although using the `\hskip` command that Charles Stewart suggested is probably even neater. I've accepted this one because it explains how to make it work in the tabbing environment.

Answer (score 11):

If you want this in math mode, put `\usepackage{amsmath}` in your preamble, and try

```
\begin{align*}
  A &\to B \\
  CD &\to A
\end{align*}
```

The ampersands are invisible, and are aligned with each other, so the arrows will line up.

This can also be done in text mode as a table (without needing the `amsmath` package):

```
\begin{tabular}{r @{$\to$} l}
  A & B \\
  CD & A
\end{tabular}
```

With the `@` expression in the column specification, the columns will be separated by whatever symbol you like -- in this case, the arrow -- thus aligning that symbol between rows.

Answer (score 8):

Use `{\hskip 4em}` to specify whitespace four font-width spaces wide, or what have you.  There are a number of prespecified whitespace characters in Latex, such as `\qquad` for `\hskip2em`.

`\hskip` whitespace specified in this way is inflexible, that is, Tex will not change the amount of whitespace, but you can use something like `{\hskip 3em plus 1em minus 1em}` for space that tries to be 3ems long, but can stretch or shorten to between 2ems and 4ems.

Comment: IMHO, you answer a different question.

Comment: @Alexey: No.  Latex's tabbing environment will set tab stops after whitespace generated using hskip, so this answer provides information on how to solve the problem.

Comment: Yep, this did answer the question, in fact I think it is a more elegant solution than the one I accepted. But given that that one also has a nice little description on how it all plays out in the tabbing environment, it's a bit more useful for people landing on this page.

Comment: This is the best answer, although I would usually prefer `\hspace`:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126200/when-should-you-use-vskip-hskip-rather-than-vspace-hspace-in-a-latex-doc

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `tabbing` (instead of e.g. `tabular`), you can use `kill` to make a "template" line that sets the stops.  See http://latex.computersci.org/Reference/TableEnvironments.